# Combine SQL query with different where clause

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I have 3 steps to produce an output table where output of first table is input to second table and so on.Only difference is the where condition clause in 3 queries.
Want to combine to improve speed and performance. Can you please suggest how to do so.Below are the queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.*
,R.Channel
,R.[Deal Description]
into Intermediate_Temp_Table1
--select count(*)
FROM Temp_Table
left join [ID vs CHANNEL_MAPPING] M ON M.Outlet_Id = A.VIP_OUTLET_ID
LEFT JOIN [product TO SUBBRAND MAPPING](nolock) B on A.BPP_CODE = B.[BPP Code] 
LEFT JOIN [DBO].[A1 VS A2] C (nolock) ON (C.[C6 CODE] = A.SHIP_TO_CUST_CODE) 
LEFT JOIN Price_Structure_FY18 R 
 ON B.[SUBBRAND ID]=R.[SUBBRAND  CODE] 
 AND C.[C5 CODE] = R.[CUSTOMER C5  CODE]
 AND CONVERT(decimal(16,2),A.NET_UNIT_PRICE) = CONVERT(decimal(16,2),R.[Suggested PTR])
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 1]
 and A.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY = R.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY
 AND  A.RDTYPE is  NULL

------------------------------------
  SELECT DISTINCT
A.*
,R.Channel
,R.[Deal Description]
into Intermediate_Temp_Table2
--select count(*)
FROM Intermediate_Temp_Table1
left join [ID vs CHANNEL_MAPPING] M ON M.Outlet_Id = A.VIP_OUTLET_ID
LEFT JOIN [product TO SUBBRAND MAPPING](nolock) B on A.BPP_CODE = B.[BPP Code] 
LEFT JOIN [DBO].[A1 VS A2] C (nolock) ON (C.[C6 CODE] = A.SHIP_TO_CUST_CODE) 
LEFT JOIN Price_Structure_FY18 R 
 ON B.[SUBBRAND ID]=R.[SUBBRAND  CODE] 
 AND C.[C5 CODE] = R.[CUSTOMER C5  CODE]
 AND CONVERT(decimal(16,2),A.NET_UNIT_PRICE) = CONVERT(decimal(16,2),R.[Suggested PTR])
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 2]
 and A.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY = R.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY
 AND  A.RDTYPE is  NULL

----------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT
A.*
,R.Channel
,R.[Deal Description]
into Intermediate_Temp_Table3
--select count(*)
FROM Intermediate_Temp_Table2
left join [ID vs CHANNEL_MAPPING] M ON M.Outlet_Id = A.VIP_OUTLET_ID
LEFT JOIN [product TO SUBBRAND MAPPING](nolock) B on A.BPP_CODE = B.[BPP Code] 
LEFT JOIN [DBO].[A1 VS A2] C (nolock) ON (C.[C6 CODE] = A.SHIP_TO_CUST_CODE) 
LEFT JOIN Price_Structure_FY18 R 
 ON B.[SUBBRAND ID]=R.[SUBBRAND  CODE] 
 AND C.[C5 CODE] = R.[CUSTOMER C5  CODE]
 AND CONVERT(decimal(16,2),A.NET_UNIT_PRICE) = CONVERT(decimal(16,2),R.[Suggested PTR])
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 3]
 and A.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY = R.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY
 AND  A.RDTYPE is  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

to accomplish this you need only one select
this is becaouse your only difference is R.Channel

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.*
,R.Channel
,R.[Deal Description]
into Intermediate_Temp_Table1
--select count(*)
FROM Temp_Table
left join [ID vs CHANNEL_MAPPING] M ON M.Outlet_Id = A.VIP_OUTLET_ID
LEFT JOIN [product TO SUBBRAND MAPPING](nolock) B on A.BPP_CODE = B.[BPP Code] 
LEFT JOIN [DBO].[A1 VS A2] C (nolock) ON (C.[C6 CODE] = A.SHIP_TO_CUST_CODE) 
LEFT JOIN Price_Structure_FY18 R 
 ON B.[SUBBRAND ID]=R.[SUBBRAND  CODE] 
 AND C.[C5 CODE] = R.[CUSTOMER C5  CODE]
 AND CONVERT(decimal(16,2),A.NET_UNIT_PRICE) = CONVERT(decimal(16,2),R.[Suggested PTR])
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 1]
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 2]
 and R.Channel = M.[CHANNEL 3]
 and A.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY = R.MONTH_END_DATE_KEY
 AND  A.RDTYPE is  NULL
```